# Multiple Connection Factories

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic, javabeans

I'm using spring boot and setting up multiple connection factories (pooled and jms). The issue I'm getting is that it seems to be trying to autowire them to the same object in javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. So its resulting in this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.jms.ConnectionFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration.connectionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: jmsConnectionFactory,pooledConnectionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: jmsConnectionFactory,pooledConnectionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 40 more
```

Here is the config I'm using:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
   <property name="brokerURL" value="***" />
</bean>
 <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
   <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConfig" 
   class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>     
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="11"/> 
   <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="11"/> 
</bean>  
<bean id="activemq" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
</bean>
```

I'm assuming the problem is that both of these classes implement the javax.jms.ConnectionFactory class and then they're autowired via ConnectionFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration. Am I missing something here, any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set primary=true on one of the connection factory beans